# How to enable Bluetooth in Windows Guest on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bluetooth

Would it be possible to enable Bluetooth in Windows Guest on VirtualBox? If so, how? I'm not find a lot of information about this. I've already installed both the Guest Addition and the Extension Pack, but that was not enough. I bought this new headphone that is not working correctly in meetings, but it does on Windows. So I would like to have a Windows guest OS that I use only for meetings. The idea here is to enable the Bluetooth on Windows Guest but also allow Windows to control the Bluetooth Adapter directly. I think the later is not possible, but a co-worker is insisting that it's possible. Unfortunately I also didn't find a lot of content about that as well.

Comment: Does your processor support VT-d?  This also requires the Bluetooth adapter support DMA.  Simplest way would be to use a USB device and attach it to the VM instead of using your built-in BT capability.

Comment: It does not! :(

Comment: If your processor does not support VT-d then you cannot attach DMA supported devices to your VM.  Get yourself a USB BT adapter and call it a day

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound :)

Comment: [Did you installed all necessary drives on Windows VM? Did you already check out Device Manager for some warning or error message for lack of drive?](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/7-ways-to-access-device-manager-in-windows-10.html)